# Can tokio::select allow defining arbitrary numbre of branches

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I am writing an echo server that is able to listen on multiple ports. My working server below relies on `select` to accept connections from 2 different listeners

However, instead of defining the listeners as individual variables, is it possible to define `select` branches based on a `Vec<TcpListener>` ?

```rust
use tokio::{io, net, select, spawn};

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let listener1 = net::TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:8001").await.unwrap();
    let listener2 = net::TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:8002").await.unwrap();

    loop {
        let (conn, _) = select! {
            v = listener1.accept() => v.unwrap(),
            v = listener2.accept() => v.unwrap(),
        };
        spawn(handle(conn));
    }
}

async fn handle(mut conn: net::TcpStream) {
    let (mut read, mut write) = conn.split();
    io::copy(&mut read, &mut write).await.unwrap();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While `futures::future::select_all()` works, it is not very elegant (IMHO) and it creates an allocation for each round. A better solution is to use streams (note this also allocates on each round, but this allocates much less):

```rust
use tokio::{io, net, spawn};
use tokio_stream::wrappers::TcpListenerStream;
use futures::stream::{StreamExt, SelectAll};

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let mut listeners = SelectAll::new();
    listeners.push(TcpListenerStream::new(net::TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:8001").await.unwrap()));
    listeners.push(TcpListenerStream::new(net::TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:8002").await.unwrap()));

    while let Some(conn) = listeners.next().await {
        let conn = conn.unwrap();
        spawn(handle(conn));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`select_all`](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/future/fn.select_all.html) function from the `futures` crate, which takes an iterator of futures and awaits *any* of them (instead of *all* of them, like `join_all` does):

```rust
use futures::{future::select_all, FutureExt};
use tokio::{io, net, select, spawn};

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let mut listeners = [
        net::TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:8001").await.unwrap(),
        net::TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:8002").await.unwrap(),
    ];

    loop {
        let (result, index, _) = select_all(
            listeners
                .iter_mut()
                // note: `FutureExt::boxed` is called here because `select_all`
                //       requires the futures to be pinned
                .map(|listener| listener.accept().boxed()),
        )
        .await;

        let (conn, _) = result.unwrap();
        spawn(handle(conn));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! `select_all` seems to do the trick. `select_ok` seem to work as well. I also tried a different approach where each listener is on its own task and queue incoming connections through an `mpsc` channel. Though I am curious what the performance difference with the 2 approaches.